# Insert/Update a cell to BLANK value into .xls using OleDB

Tags: .net, asp.net, excel, oledb

I'm reading time values from an Excel spreadsheet displaying in a GridView. The user can update these values. When calling the OleDB `UPDATE`, I am passing in the format `3:00 PM`.
If the user deletes a time from the GridView (essentially passing in `""` to my update method) I'd like the Excel file to show a blank cell. However, I keep getting a `Data type mismatch in criteria expression.` error when trying to update the cell with `""`. It also throws an error when passing in null.

Everything I've found so far deals with *reading* blank values. What do I `UPDATE`/`INSERT` the cell with to have it show up as blank?

Comment: Does your database allow a null values in that field? 
Is this a new record insert, or an update?

Comment: It's not going into a database, it's going into an Excel file.

Comment: So excel is acting as the database and you are inserting to it with your code? Any code sample of what you are passing in and how?

Comment: I ended up not using OleDB but a rather nice library called EPPlus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though this is old but i ran into this same issue and got it resolved using

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter(i, DBNull.Value))

dbnull.value.
```